# How to get required XML element from not well formed XML data in SQL server

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath

In my SQL 2008 database table, I have one column name AUTHOR that contains XML data. The XML is not well formed and has data like below

```
<Author>
<ID>172-32-1176</ID>
<LastName>White</LastName>
<FirstName>Johnson</FirstName>
<Address>
<Street>10932 Bigge Rd.</Street>
<City>Menlo Park</City>
<State>CA</State>
</Address>
</Author>
```

Some XML have all of above data and some have just one tag.

```
<ID>172-32-1176</ID>
```

I want to write query that returns me a column as identiry.
I tried using AUTHOR.query('data(/Author/ID)') as identity but it fails when XML does not have Author node.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like `/Author/ID|/ID` ? i.e. try for the first scenario, and with no match, the second ?

(note that the `|` operator is a set union operator, as described [here](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/andAndOr.html))

Answer (score 0):

In case that nothing "certain" can be maintained about the XML, except that a unique `ID` element contains the required identity value, then the following XPath expression selects the `ID` element:

```
//ID
```

Comment: One thing you should know about this statement is that it doesn't perform very well. If your documents are large, I would avoid this.

Comment: @Eric-T: Sure -- I always mention this. This is why I say that this is to be used only "In case that nothing "certain" can be maintained about the XML"